# Microsoft apps always eating up space with data, for apparently no reason

Tags: internal-storage, ms-office

Microsoft apps (Excel, PowerPoint, Word) use up space apparently for no reason.
At this point, I do not use them.
I am using a Samsung J7 with Android 6, with 16Gb internal storage and no SD card.

Since I often run out of space, I check which apps are using it. I always find Microsoft apps are taking up space **for data**, and this seems strange to me.

For instance, I go to *Settings* -> *Applications* -> *Application Manager* -> *Word* -> *Storage*,
and I see:

```
Total 256 MB
App 104 MB
Data 152 MB
```

*Why would Word use 152 MB **of Data**, if I did not read/use any?*

I hit `CLEAR DATA` not long ago, and I checked that the corresponding storage space was actually freed to `0 MB`.
Now it is taking again `152 MB`.

*What are those data?*

It is not that much space, but in my case it makes a difference.

Excel and PowerPoint behave similarly.

A stranger case seems to be OneNote, with

```
Total 3.89 MB
App 0 MB
Data 3.89 MB
```

**EDIT**: Now, two days after the initial post, Word takes up 16 kB. That is fine. I will check periodically to see when it increases Data size.

**EDIT**: A couple of months after the initial OP, without using any of the apps, Excel had 251Mb of Data.

Comment: If you never use them - remove them.

Comment: @Alex.S - I currently do not use them, and I certainly considered removing them. But I am not certain I would not use them in the (near?) future.

Comment: @sancho.s Microsoft's Word and Excel are heavy because they are feature rich. You have so many alternatives like DocsToGo, Smart Office, WPS Office which are all-in-one type of apps. I use DocsToGo for viewing documents because I never edit documents on mobile. It is a pain to do so.

Comment: @MANI - The question is about the size of **Data**, not **App**, so I guess the comment does not address the OP. Anyway, thanks for the suggested app.