# An error has occurred with the fingerprint sensor

Tags: fingerprint

Shortly ago, my J7 Prime stopped recognizing my fingerprint.

When I go to
*Settings* ->
*Lock screen and security* ->
*Fingerprint Scanner*
I get

> An error has occurred with the fingerprint sensor. If this message appears repeatedly, restart your device.

I tried a few options I found, and none worked:

1. Rebooting.
2. Going into Safe Mode. The same error appears. Plus, almost all my widgets in the home screen disappeared, so I had to redo it.
3. *Settings* ->
   *Apps* ->
   *Three dots* ->
   *Show system apps* ->
   *Fingerprint* ->
   *Clear Data*
   . The cache was already empty.
   Rebooting.
4. Logging off and into my Samsung account.
5. *Developer options* (this was already enabled) ->
   *OEM unlock* ->
   *Enable*.
   Reboot.
   *Developer options* ->
   *OEM unlock* ->
   *Disable*, and 
   *Developer options* ->
   *Disable*.

What I did not (and I cannot) try:

1. Rooting my phone (it is a corporate device).
2. Resetting my phone (same).

**What can I do to fix the problem?** (other than taking it to the IT dept.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a system update pending. 
After I updated the fingerprint sensor came back to life.

(Note: Not only that... about 1.5GB were freed, which I very much needed. Unfortunately, Android's gluttony will promptly take care of it.)

I cannot propose this as a general solution as:

1. I am not sure it will always work (although after the update there were a few glitches that got fixed, so I guess there are chances it will work).
2. This depends on the existence of a pending update, which will not always be available.

Comment: That's disturbing. Locking the fingerprint scanner to get you to update?

Comment: This didn't help me, seems like a problem with the finger print sensor itself.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the problem is with the fingerprint scanner itself.  He was either damaged or moved away from the water, and he burned

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I Fixed this issue. I have Note 9  Phone.

You need to Remove and Reconnect your Battery.. I know its not Possible becouse Latest Phones Are Seeltype by itself.

But samsung give option for simmulate pull battry and reconnect. Its not lost any data.

Press Power button + Volume Down Button Same time and keep 30 Second

Then phone will be restart and try again your fingerprints.